# Find the weak derivative

Tags: weak-derivatives

I want to find the weak derivative of $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(1,2)$. So basically it is constant ae.

I was expecting the weak derivative to be $0$. However, when calculating, I'm getting a different answer. Is the weak derivative of $f$ not $0$?

Comment: What did you calculate?

Comment: It's not what I would think of as "constant ae". If the weak derivative were $0$ then it would be constant ae, meaning that there would exist $c$ such that $f=c$ ae.

Comment: Did my response answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following

> **Lemma:**
> Let $u'$ be the weak derivative of $u$ on $(a,b)$. Then for all intervals $(\alpha, \beta) \subset (a,b)$ it holds that $u'|_{(\alpha, \beta)}$ is also the weak derivative of $u|_{(\alpha, \beta)}$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$.

**Proof.**
Let $(\alpha, \beta) \subset (a,b)$ and $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(\alpha, \beta)$ and define the trivial extension of $\phi$ by $\tilde{\phi} \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(a,b)$.
Then, we conclude
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} u(x) \phi'(x) dx
  = \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \tilde{\phi}'(x) dx
  = - \int_{a}^{b} u'(x) \tilde{\phi}(x) dx
  = - \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} u'(x) \phi(x) dx,
\end{equation*}
which implies the proposition.$\ \square$

**Back to your question:**
This implies, as you rightly point out, that the only candidate for the weak derivative of your function has to be
\begin{equation*}
v(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x \in (0,1), \\
0, & \text{if } x \in (1, 2)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
If $v$ is the weak derivative of $u$, for all test functions $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(0,2)$ the following has to hold:
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{0}^{2} u(x) \phi'(x) dx
    = - \int_{0}^{2} v(x) \phi(x) dx.  
\end{equation*}
Now,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{0}^{2} f(x) \phi'(x)
    = \int_{0}^{1} \phi'(x)
    = \phi(1) - \phi(0)
    = \phi(1)
    \neq 0
    = - \int_{0}^{2} v(x) \phi(x).
\end{equation*}
for all test functions with $\phi(1) \neq 0$, which I'm sure you believe exist.
Therefore, your function is not weakly differentiable.